# What are some quality metrics of a Bayesian Probabilistic Model?

Tags: bayesian, metric

I'm building a [Bayesian Probabilistic Model](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/myllymak/bnets.pdf) and have been researching ways to assess the quality of the model but haven't found much.

Any recommendation would be much appreciated.

[Edit: Providing more context]

I'm building a model that will predict the likelihood that an event will occur given a number of past events.

Comment: Same ones as with every other kind of models. Could you try being more specific?

Comment: I've added an edit but I'll repeat here: I'm building a model that will predict the likelihood that an event will occur given a number of past events. I'm not quite sure what metrics help assess how well it is doing.

Comment: what you have described is an *extremely* wide class of models, so it's hard to give any advice outside of "check that the estimated probabilities match with observed event frequencies".

Comment: Your edit does not change anything: you can use same ones as for any other model (e.g. logistic regression).